# Buzzing/Vibration in body under power lines

Tags: electricity, vibrations

I am hoping someone can please give me an answer.  I was at a dog park with my dog and son (hes 12), which is directly under high/loud voltage power lines.  I went to brush some dirt of my sons neck when I felt his neck "buzzing".  He didnt feel it. I felt all over him, and he was buzzing/vibrating all over his entire body, head, legs arms. It was not due to a vibraton from the ground. We could not feel it on myself. I had someone else come over and feel his arm to conrim I wasnt loosing my mind!  I had him take everything out of his pockets to see if that was the cause, and he was still buzzing. We went back to the car, which was not directly under but still close enough to power lines and he continued buzzing until we left the vicinity of the power lines.  Can someone please help and explain this weird situation that has happened. I am very concered/worried/etc.

Comment: Sounds like electrostatic pickup from the power lines that you could feel because his shoes were better insulated than yours, or posibly the other way around.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29016/2451