# Electromagnetic fields and human behaviour

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, biophysics

To what extent does electromagnetic fields and/or radiation from space have influence on human behaviour and/or physiology?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29016/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Interesting question. The answer has to be "it depends" on what you mean. Obviously, light from the sun enables all life on Earth. Cut it out, and the planet would freeze in a few days, the atmosphere would liquify a short time later, and eventually it would rain down and freeze over a dead, dark planet with no life.

On the other hand, if you restrict the problem to high energy particles that reach the surface of Earth on a normal day (without nearby supernovae etc.), cosmic radiation plays a non-trivial role in changes to DNA and it may be responsible for a non-trivial number of cancers.

Answer (score -1):

The visible and radio waves can cause heating effect when absorbed by the living cells.  Human mind is effected by the electromagnetic waves and can change moods of a person.  Higher radiations like Ultraviolet, X rays and Gama radiations can produce damage to life at powers that produce little heating.